# Wifi - No Adaptors listed in WPA_GUI

Tags: raspbian, wireless

I bought this [wifi adaptor from Adafruit](http://www.adafruit.com/products/814) (RTl8192cu chipset).  I plugged it directly into the raspberrypi and started it up.  But I didn't have the wpa_gui app and I guess I didn't have the latest raspian so I tried to get that upgrade first.

I ran

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
sudo apt-get install raspberrypi* raspi-config
```

And then I followed the [instructions on this page](http://www.raspberrypi.org/phpBB3/viewtopic.php?t=17788) up to the create netdev user step.  But I still don't see any adaptors listed when I launch WPA_GUI.  I really thought this thing would be plug and play :-(  The Adafruit site seemed to imply that ...

Can anyone help?  I'm really not good at hardcore Linux hacking.

Comment: what does the command `lsusb` show?  My unit displays as `Bus 001 Device 004: ID 0bda:8176 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. RTL8188CUS 802.11n WLAN Adapter`

Comment: Yes, I see exactly that.

Comment: Other things I noticed: WPA_GUI in the status area says "Could not get status from WPA_SUPPLICANT"

Comment: Also a message I saw flash by when it was starting up: "couldn't read interfaces file: /etc/network/interfaces".  I wonder if that means something?

Comment: Are you running the WPA_GUI as root?  i.e. `wudo WPA_GUI`  I setup mine manually using the command line.

Comment: I just tried sudo wpa_gui. But it didn't seem to make a difference.

Comment: Do you have a `/etc/network/interfaces` file?  What does it contain?

Answer (score 2):

Yay I got it working!  It turns out I had a line split over two lines in the interface file. That's what I get for copying the settings from my phone!

Thanks for all the help.

Comment: I have exactly the same issue as you right now, with the same adapter according to `lsusb`. What does your `/etc/network/interfaces` file look like? I think mine's fine, but I can't be sure. Very frustrating!

Answer (score 0):

in my case I had a line starting with `wpa-roam` while it should be `wpa-conf` in my `/etc/network/interfaces` file. After I changed it and did `ifdown wlan0 && ifup wlan0`, the adapter appeared

i was following this tutorial for the rest of the `interfaces` file, btw: http://weworkweplay.com/play/automatically-connect-a-raspberry-pi-to-a-wifi-network/